# cannot access data in mongo (added by tweepy)

Tags: python, mongodb, tweepy

I am running the code below. At the end I am trying to access the data that was stored in Mongo. I am new to Mongo and cannot figure out how to reference it so that I can get the text field (or any field). Nothing prints out when I do print(text).

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=10):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit

    def on_data(self, data):

        while (time.time() - self.time) <  self.limit:
            #print(data)
            try:


                client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
                db = client['twitter_db']
                collection = db['twitter_collection']
                tweet = json.loads(data)

                collection.insert(tweet)

                return True


            except BaseException as e:
                print('failed ondata,') 
                print(str(e))
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(statuses)


#tweets_iterator = twitter_db.collection.find()
tweets_iterator = twitter_db.find()
for tweet in tweets_iterator:
    #print(tweet['text'])   
    text = tweet['text']
    print(text)
print(db.twitter_db.count())
```

Comment: How is `twitter_db` defined?

Comment: Can you try this?                                                                        tweets_iterator = twitter_db.collection.find()                                                         for tweet in tweets_iterator: #print(tweet['text'])

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that runs:

```
tweets_iterator = collection.find()
for tweet in tweets_iterator:
    text = tweet['text']  
    print(text)
print(collection.count())
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: Can you double check if you have this data on local mongodb in database twitter_db and collection  twitter_collection

Comment: I have a folder called C:\data\db

Comment: don't know how to check about the name twitter_db or twitter_collection. I don't see anything like that in the folder C:\data\db

Comment: in that folder there is a file called collection-2--7451484256103046941.wt  which was updated at the time I ran my code. There is no file with a name like twitter...

Comment: connect to mongodb running on your local machine using mongo shell.                   https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#connect-to-mongodb

Comment: I think I was already connected but just in case I ran it again from a new Windows cmd. Like this: PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> .\mongo.exe
2016-05-08T22:30:16.762+0900 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data f
iles
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: test

Answer (score 0):

Download [Mongochef Client](http://3t.io/mongochef/), install or run from binary file.

Connect using your IP and port details. Once connection is established, you can easily view the collection, documents and entire structure stored in your database

Comment: Thank you. I used localhost:27017 for MongoChef. I assumed localhost was correct and 27017 was automatically suggested by MongoChef. I see three icons in the left panel of MongoChef: local, test, and twitter_db. Under twitter_db, I see twitter_collection, and under that I see id.

Comment: Are you able to see the data you have inserted ?